# phonegap file transfer with space in the file name

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova 1.9.0 for an Android App. The same code, on IOS works fine.
On Android, i find a problem for the file trasfert from remote location to local. 
The problem is on the file name: someone has space. I try to do

```
.replace(" ","%20")
```

but doesn't work. It gives me the following error

07-03 12:06:32.503: E/FileTransfer(337): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.mydomain.com/sa02 -.jpg

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: This link is just an example, is not a real link.

Comment: have you tried using `encodeURI(file path here)`??

Comment: Now i will try and i reply soon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in FileTransfer upload which a fix was checked in for 1.9.0.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-978

Comment: In this moment this link doesn't work. But thanks for this issue...i will check

Comment: Yeah, JIRA has a tendency to not be available on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap 1.9.0 and 2.0.0 break `fileTransfer.download()` for names with spaces.
The workaround for now until PhoneGap 2.1.0 comes out is

```
var source = encodeURI(file path here);
source = source.replace(/%/g,"%25");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = url.replace(/ /g,"%20");
```